# Adding images side by side in pdf using itextsharp

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I am writing some data to the pdf using itextsharp. I am adding 2 images. I used this code:

```
 iTextSharp.text.Image img = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath + "\\t.jpg");
 iTextSharp.text.Image img2 = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath + "\\teiasLogo.jpg");
 pdfDocCreatePDF.Add(img);
 pdfDocCreatePDF.Add(img2);
```

I want to see them like that :
[image]

As a result I don't want new line ( \n ) between the images, I want spaces. How can I do that? Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can produce that by using PdfPTable. Create a new table. Then you can assign your images to each cell (with border=0).

Answer (score 1):

```
 PdfPTable resimtable = new PdfPTable(2); // two colmns create tabble
 resimtable.WidthPercentage = 100f;//table %100 width
 iTextSharp.text.Image imgsag = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(Application.StartupPath+"/sagkulak.jpg");
iTextSharp.text.Image imgsol = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(Application.StartupPath + "/sagkulak.jpg");
resimtable.AddCell(imgsag);//Table One colmns added first image
resimtable.AddCell(imgsol);//Table two colmns added second image
```